# Iframe with sandbox doesnot allow new window/tabs pop up in firefox

Tags: html, iframe, sandbox

I am opening a webpage in an iFrame.

I have sandbox attributes set with properties in it to allow popups and scripts.

The web page displayed in iFrame is supposed to create a new tab/window or window popup on clicking the link.

My Iframe:

```
<html>
<body>

<iframe 
    style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 1000px;"
    src="http://www.textfixer.com/html/jquery-pop-up-window-example.php" 
    sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

The links works fine in IE but not in Firefox. I need to find a solution for this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As an FYI, there is the button `{ }` on the toolbar. If you highlight your code and select the button, it will automatically add a blank line at the start and end, while indenting the text four spaces. This marks text as 'code'. :-)

Answer (score 3):

`allow-popups` is now supported since Firefox 27

Comment: in [Chrome](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox/) too

Answer (score 0):

allow-popup is not supported on firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=766282

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response . It is marked as resolved, but my firefox is updated and i am still facing this issue. I guess it is not included as an update yet.